# Centos SSH Ports stops responding

Tags: centos, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a couple AWS instances running CentOS. Every few days the SSH ports stop connecting on both instances. When I try to SSH into the server it just keeps trying to connect and doesn't timeout. Hence I am not able to login into the server at all. The apache service works fine and website is served with no issues.

The only solution is to restart the instance. After restart it will run fine for a few days and SSH stops again after few days.

I have spoken to AWS support and they could not find anything. The logs also don't show anything and the logs stop logging after the issue starts.

Need help where to start troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Can you access a KVM console? If logging stops, it sounds more like the entire server is crashing.

Comment: What is KVM console in AWS? Whole server is not crashing as apache is working fine and website is loading fine

Comment: any help please

Comment: @Chris When you login use the verbose.mode like this: `ssh -vvv ...` (consider using the three `v`). That command will produce a more detailed output about what is happening (maybe the command is waiting for something)